# Windows MaTeX Configuration

Tags: latex, matex

I configured Ghostscript but not sure why pdflatex was not configured.

this is how Ghostscript is done:

```
ConfigureMaTeX[
 "Ghostscript" -> 
  "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\gs\\gs9.54.0\\bin\\gswin32c.exe"]

  pdfLaTeX is not found at /usr/bin/pdflatex

Please configure pdfLaTeX using ConfigureMaTeX["pdfLaTeX" -> "path to 
pdflatex executable\[Ellipsis]"]

Click here for documentation on configuring MaTeX.
```

output:

```
 {"CacheSize" -> 100, "WorkingDirectory" -> Automatic,  
"pdfLaTeX" -> "/usr/bin/pdflatex", 
 "Ghostscript" -> 
 "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\gs\\gs9.54.0\\bin\\gswin32c.exe"}
  ConfigureMaTeX[
 "pdfLaTeX" -> "C:\\texlive\\2021\\bin\\win32\\xelatex.exe" , 
 "Ghostscript" -> 
  "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\gs\\gs9.54.0\\bin\\gswin32c.exe"]
```

I added the path for pdflatex and it gives output as the same as the input:

```
ConfigureMaTeX[
"pdfLaTeX" -> "C:\\texlive\\2021\\bin\\win32\\xelatex.exe" , 
"Ghostscript" -> 
 "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\gs\\gs9.54.0\\bin\\gswin32c.exe"]
```

output:

```
 ConfigureMaTeX[
 "pdfLaTeX" -> "C:\\texlive\\2021\\bin\\win32\\xelatex.exe", 
 "Ghostscript" -> 
 "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\gs\\gs9.54.0\\bin\\gswin32c.exe"]
```

checking if successfully installed any of them:

```
 << MaTeX`

 pdfLaTeX is not found at /usr/bin/pdflatex

 Please configure pdfLaTeX using ConfigureMaTeX["pdfLaTeX" -> "path to 
 pdflatex executable\[Ellipsis]"]

 Click here for documentation on configuring MaTeX.
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Instead of just saying "it did not work", show a complete example: what did you do exactly? What happened? If there was an error message, show it in full. Please update the question with this information.

Comment: This is not a complete example. You need to provide enough information that people can reproduce what you did precisely.

Comment: The documentation has detailed instructions on how to configure MaTeX. Without more information about what you did specifically, I cannot say more than point to the documentation. I am trying to help you, but I cannot unless you provide the information I requested in the above two comments: 1. Follow the documentation to the best of your abilities. 2. Describe what you are _actually_ doing in sufficient detail that another person, who is not standing next to your computer, could reproduce your steps.

Comment: What OS do you use? Restart Mathematica, then enter the commands to set up MaTeX. Show us every command you evaluated, precisely in the manner you are doing it. If there are error messages, indicate what they are.  Note that this question will be closed as un-answerable unless improved.

Comment: You did not provide a coherent example we can use as a starting point even after three requests for clarification, so I give up on this. I will point out that  you appear to be mixing Windows and Linux paths on the same system, and that the `pdfLaTeX` path was quite clearly not set to a pdflatex executable (even ignoring the question whether there is a file present at the given path).

Comment: I finally configured ghostscript but I still could not find the right pdfLaTeX path. How should I set the path for pdfLaTeX correctly?